# How can I make symbolic links in one folder for multiple files in another folder

Tags: command-line, themes, gnome-shell, symbolic-link

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, 19.04 & 19.10

For `gnome-shell` theming purposes, I come across the below situation.

```
admin@i7-4770:~$ ls /usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/
calendar-today.svg               noise-texture.png
checkbox-dark.svg                no-notifications.svg
checkbox-focused-dark.svg        pad-osd.css
checkbox-focused.svg             pointer-double-click-symbolic.svg
checkbox-off-dark.svg            pointer-drag-symbolic.svg
checkbox-off-focused-dark.svg    pointer-primary-click-symbolic.svg
checkbox-off-focused.svg         pointer-secondary-click-symbolic.svg
checkbox-off.svg                 process-working.svg
checkbox.svg                     running-indicator.svg
dash-placeholder.svg             source-button-border.svg
gnome-shell.css                  summary-counter.svg
gnome-shell-high-contrast.css    toggle-off-dark.svg
key-enter.svg                    toggle-off-hc.svg
key-hide.svg                     toggle-off-intl.svg
key-layout.svg                   toggle-off.svg
key-shift-latched-uppercase.svg  toggle-on-dark.svg
key-shift.svg                    toggle-on-hc.svg
key-shift-uppercase.svg          toggle-on-intl.svg
lockscreen-gradient.svg          toggle-on.svg
logged-in-indicator.svg          ws-switch-arrow-down.svg
message-indicator-symbolic.svg   ws-switch-arrow-up.svg
no-events.svg
admin@i7-4770:~$
```

I need to create a symbolic link for every `.svg` and  `.png` files from above output in the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/` directory.

Right now, my only way is to run `ln -s` for each file.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/calendar-today.svg /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/
```

I am sure, experts can make it very quick.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can link from directory to directory, but this will make **all** files in source directory available in the destination directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a loop at all here. Just run this `ln` command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/*{png,svg} /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/
```

Brace expansion is handled by the shell, before launching any command. So the command above becomes:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/noise-texture.png  /usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/checkbox-dark.svg [...] /usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/ws-switch-arrow-up.svg /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/
```

In other words, it becomes `ln -s f1 f2 ... fN /path/to/target/dir` and that is all you need to link all your files. For example:

```
$ ls foo/
file1.svg  file2.svg  file3.svg  file4.png  file5.png  file6.png
$ ln -s $HOME/foo/*{svg,png} bar/
$ ls -l bar/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 26 Dec 26 12:16 file1.svg -> /home/terdon/foo/file1.svg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 26 Dec 26 12:16 file2.svg -> /home/terdon/foo/file2.svg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 26 Dec 26 12:16 file3.svg -> /home/terdon/foo/file3.svg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 26 Dec 26 12:16 file4.png -> /home/terdon/foo/file4.png
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 26 Dec 26 12:16 file5.png -> /home/terdon/foo/file5.png
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 26 Dec 26 12:16 file6.png -> /home/terdon/foo/file6.png
```

If you just have to have a loop for some reason, use globs instead:

```
for file in /usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/*{png,svg}; do
    sudo ln -s "$file" /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/
done
```

This way, you don't need to worry about any weird file names, as you would [when using `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Also note how I am quoting `"$file"` which is also [essential](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222) for strange file names.

Answer (score 1):

after several googling..

ended up with below script

```
#!/bin/bash

for p in $(ls /usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell | grep '.svg\|.png'); do
    sudo ln -s /usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/$p /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/
done
```

It worked. But I still think experts can make it with a single command which can be entered into terminal.

Comment: Do you really need a loop? You can do it in one command, just like: `ln -sf /usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/*.{svg,png} /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/` See `man ln`.

Comment: This means that there are no `.svg` and `.png` files in the source directory: `/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/`

Comment: @PRATAP no, that isn't what it simplifies to. It becomes `ln -sf /usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/*.svg /usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/*.png /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/`. If it only created two files for you, then there are no files that match the glob `/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/*.svg` or `/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/*.png` as Fedon said.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli sorry there was a error from my side for running the command.. I forgot `gnome-shell` text in the path `/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/` previously..

Comment: @PRATAP yes, as you explained you were using the wrong path. If you still have questions about this, please come into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) so we don't clutter up the comments.